# how to use variable data from java bean to jsp page and vice versa

Tags: java, algorithm, jakarta-ee, transactions, credit-card

I have a quite difficult issue of code implementation.

i'm trying to implement credit card fraud transaction using HMM(Hidden Markov model).
i tried all algo , but not able to understand how to implement it.

basic implementation is we are accessing last transaction from any database take here as a Ms Access.

then how to put those trasaction in HMM algo and how to get variant/fraud output.

Please to all ! Just i'm expecting help from you..

Thanks in Advance to all :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsp:useBean tag to access and set the value of your bean's properties inside jsp.
See if this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_java_beans.htm) will work.

Comment: your reference tutorial is using data from jsp page i mean <jsp:setProperty name="students" property="firstName"
                    value="Zara"/>  i want value from java bean which is in my resultset.

Comment: You can set your bean property like this- bean.setFirstname(rs.getString("fname"));

Comment: userid :
        <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" value="<%= user %>">    this data is on my jsp page ... but i want to use value of userid in java then how i do this...?

Comment: When you are submit a form then you can get this parameter in your Servlet through form action like this request.getParameter("userid");. Set your bean like bean.setUserid(request.getParameter("userid");.

Comment: yeah solved...but here another issu again...i put resultset value in list and finded sum on all values which are in list this code is in simple java bean but i want to use this "avg" on jsp for showing purpose.....Please solve this...

Comment: If inside list is int type value you can get the sum of list as 
`int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<ls.size();i++)
    {
//ls is your list
     sum+=ls.get(i);
    }
bean.setAvg(sum);//provided if avg is int type property 

`
and get it inside jsp like this
`<jsp:getProperty name="{Bean id}" property="avg"/>`
as described in link.

Comment: bean.setAvg(sum);  in this what is it bean. as u mentioned.

Comment: bean is the object name of java bean class which you have mentioned in your question.
`YourJavaBeanClassName bean= new YourJavaBeanClassName ();`
Please update your question its little ambiguous.